# Regex using javascript to return multiple numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

in another article on Stackoverflow, I found this line of code

```
myString = 'hello112';
myNumber = myString.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

In this case, the 'myNumber' variable has the value of 122.

But when I use .match for the following case, it fails:

```
myColor = 'rgb(210,255,105);
myNumbers = myColor.match(/\d+/);
```

The 'myNumbers'variable is an array, but it's length is 1 and it contains only '210' and not the other 2 numbers.

Is there a way in Javascript that I can achive something like this?

```
input = 'rgb(210,255,105);
output = [210,255,105];
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: use the global modifier `g`: `/\d+/g`

Answer (score 3):

Unless told otherwise, `match()` matches only the first instance, not all. You need the global "g" flag after the pattern.

```
match(/pattern/g);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Side note: you can't use the global modifier in conjunction with sub-group matching, but that shouldn't affect your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `g` - global flag.

```js
myColor = 'rgb(210,255,105)';
console.log(myColor.match(/\d+/g));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! Have a nice day bro :)

Comment: @LanMai My pleasure, have a great day too.